# Get a property from an array that is in a json, with vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I have a json with events that I get it with this.$http.get from the backend. I have to output in the page event name, description, ... and polygons(witch are locations).

Here in these polygons I have the name of the location, witch I don't know how to output it with binding in the page.

```
    GET /event

{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "errorMessage": null,
  "events": [
    {
      "errorCode": 0,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "rid": "1",
      "eventName": "ev1",
      "description": "desc1",
      "startDate": 1503262800000,
      "endDate": 1503262800000,
      "ownerId": 1,
      "active": true,
      "deleted": false,
      "polygons": [
        {
          "errorCode": 0,
          "errorMessage": null,
          "rid": "1",
          "name": "loc1",
          "companyBranchId": 1,
          "filePath": "file1",
          "imagePath": "img1",
          "color": "col1",
          "active": true,
          "deleted": false,
          "links": []
        }
      ],
      "nrOfInvitees": 0,
      "ids": [],
      "visitors": [],
      "links": []
    },
    {
      "errorCode": 0,
      "errorMessage": null,
      "rid": "2",
      "eventName": "ev2",
      "description": "desc2",
      "startDate": 1503262800000,
      "endDate": 1503262800000,
      "ownerId": 1,
      "active": true,
      "deleted": false,
      "polygons": [
        {
          "errorCode": 0,
          "errorMessage": null,
          "rid": "2",
          "name": "loc2",
          "companyBranchId": 2,
          "filePath": "file2",
          "imagePath": "img2",
          "color": "col2",
          "active": true,
          "deleted": false,
          "links": []
        }
      ],
      "nrOfInvitees": 0,
      "ids": [],
      "visitors": [],
      "links": []
    },
  ]
}

<div class="event-title">
  <span>{{event.eventName}}</span>
</div>
<div class="event-address">
  <span><i class="ti-location-pin"></i> {{event.polygons.name}}</span>
</div>
```

Getting the event name, description or date was easy but when I try to output the polygons.name I don't get anything in the page.

```
<div class="event-title">
  <span>{{event.eventName}}</span>
</div>
<div class="event-address">
  <span><i class="ti-location-pin"></i> {{event.polygons.name}}</span>
</div>
```

I get the data in this above Event.vue from Events.vue

```
<app-event v-for="event in events" :event="event" :key="event.rid"></app-event>
```

I tried to do

```
{{JSON.stringify(event.polygons.name)}}
```

but I get only the first location name from the whole list, so in the page I get only one event displayed.

Please, someone, can tell me how to get in the page the polygons name?

Answer (score 0):

Polygons is an array, so to get the 1st item:

```
<span v-if="event.polygons.length !== 0"><i class="ti-location-pin"></i> {{event.polygons[0].name}}</span>
```

Or iterate over it:

```
<span v-if="event.polygons.length !== 0" v-for="polygon in event.polygons"><i class="ti-location-pin"></i> {{polygon.name}}</span>
```

Comment: My friend with first line I get ```"TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"``` and  I get  only one event in page with the location. For second line I get the same error, I get all the events in page but only for the first one I get the location.

Comment: Do all events contain a polygons array? I updated the answer with a check for the polygons array, assuming the event always contains a polygons array that might be empty

Comment: I updated the json so will will see that each event contains polygons because can be more that one locations. I still get the same error my friend even I put that v-if. Keep in mind that this html code is in component that comes from the parent Events.vue, where I have a v-for for all events. Outputting this `{{event.polygons.length}}` I get 1. So I guess the whole work has to be done in the parent where I do the v-for, but I tried many solutions with no good result. I need like 2 v-for on the same line :).